# Prevent popup to stay on top of newly launched modal windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a window that uses popup. The popup is set to stay open as required by the specification. This window also launches a new modal window. The problem I am having is that the new modal window appears on top on the original window but not the popup. The popup appear on top of everything making it all look very weird.

Comment: WPF Popup is by default topmost, but you can use something like NotTopMost popup. For example have a look here: https://gist.github.com/903202

Comment: NotTopMost inspired me to create a simple behavior that solve the problem for me nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PopupParentWindowFocusBehavior : Behavior<Popup>
{
    private bool _hidden;
    private UIElement _lastPlacementTarget;
    private System.Windows.Window _lastWindow;
    private PropertyChangeNotifier _placementTargetNotifier;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        InitializeForPlacementTarget();

        _placementTargetNotifier = new PropertyChangeNotifier(AssociatedObject, Popup.PlacementTargetProperty).AddValueChanged(OnPlacementTargetChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        DetachWindowEvents();

        if (_lastPlacementTarget != null)
        {
            ((Control)_lastPlacementTarget).Loaded -= OnPlacementTargetLoaded;
        }
        _placementTargetNotifier.ValueChanged -= OnPlacementTargetChanged;
    }

    private void OnPlacementTargetChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeForPlacementTarget();
    }

    private void InitializeForPlacementTarget()
    {
        if (_lastPlacementTarget != null)
        {
            ((Control)_lastPlacementTarget).Loaded -= OnPlacementTargetLoaded;
        }
        if (AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget != null)
        {
            ((Control)AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget).Loaded += OnPlacementTargetLoaded;
            AttachWindowEvents();
        }
        _lastPlacementTarget = AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget;
    }

    private void OnPlacementTargetLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AttachWindowEvents();
    }

    private void OnWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DetachWindowEvents();
    }

    private void AttachWindowEvents()
    {
        if (_lastWindow != null)
        {
            DetachWindowEvents();
        }

        System.Windows.Window window = System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget);
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.Deactivated += OnWindowDeativated;
            window.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
            window.Closed += OnWindowClosed;
        }

        _lastWindow = window;
    }

    private void DetachWindowEvents()
    {
        if (_lastWindow != null)
        {
            _lastWindow.Deactivated -= OnWindowDeativated;
            _lastWindow.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
            _lastWindow.Closed -= OnWindowClosed;
        }
    }

    private void OnWindowDeativated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Window window = System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget);
        if (window != null && AssociatedObject.IsOpen)
        {
            _hidden = true;
            AssociatedObject.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_hidden)
        {
            _hidden = false;
            AssociatedObject.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had pretty good luck with the [**NonTopmostPopup**](https://gist.github.com/903202) that Adrian Faciu mentioned.  It is topmost only to its parent window, so, assuming your modal window is indeed a new `Window` (not just another control that looks like one), it should work well.  If I recall, the only slight issue with it was a very occasional flicker or refresh period depending on the Windows being dragged in front of it, etc (but it was not enough of an issue for me to not use it).

Answer (score 0):

The Popup is a control that it is very useful in XBAP where you cannot (or if you do it someway you get a security warning) open a second window because of permissions and the Popup is a convienient way to display message box. If you are working in a normal WPF I recommend you to use a normal window (with WindowStyle.None if you want) instead of a Popup.

Said that, as far as I know the Popup is always shown on top and I didn't find anyway to avoid this.

Ref :: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/7467957a-08e9-4e9b-a03f-51c79a94bccb